# Flex in IntelliJ: Embeded fonts not showing after compile

Tags: actionscript-3, intellij-idea, flex4

I'm trying to set up an old Flex project in IntelliJ IDEA but are having a problem with all embeded fonts. The font is installed on my Windows 7 PC and are also located in the folder fonts in the directory where my ActionScript sources are located. I'm using the SDK compiler config from flex_sdk_4.1 with additional option of -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=true.

Code example:

```
{
[Embed(source="fonts/ORG_V01_.TTF", fontName="Org_v01", mimeType='application/x-font-truetype')]
public var Org_v01:Class;

var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
format.font = "Org_v01";
format.color = 0x000000;
format.size = 8;

label = new TextField();
label.defaultTextFormat = format;
label.embedFonts = true;
label.text = "LOADING...";
addChild(label);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Needed to set embedAsCFF='false'